# How to define nodes as arrival points and destination points

Tags: database, string, nodes, anylogic

This is probably an easy question but I do not get it.
In my model I want to create orders based on real data, in this real data there is a start location , I set those as parameter value of the order agent from the database see pictures below:

[Database anylogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd8eO.png)

[Parameters order agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgw45.png)

Now I want at the source block to let the order arrive at the departement, which is exactly the same name as the string parameter of the order, so I did this:

[Source part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vevtj.png)

But it says, cannot convert from string to Inode, so my question is how do I type the syntax that he converts the string name to the node with exactly the same name, because the departement node also is called Departement1 etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have liked to put this answer as a comment, as I'm still a relative beginner at AnyLogic and I'm sure there are more elegant approaches, but due to lack of reputation, here it it:

You can get the `String` value of the name of an `INode` object with `INode.getName()`, as documented here : https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/markup/INode.html#getName()

After which it would only be a matter of creating a creating a list that contains your nodes, creating a function that iterates through that list and fills out a Map with the name/node pair.

You can then use another function  within your agent to assign the corresponding node to a variable inside your agent, and use that to dynamically define their arrival location.

Assuming you've created a Map of name `col_nodeNameMatch`, you'd then do something like :

```
for (INode n : col_nodes) {
    if (n.getName().equals(departement)){
         col_nodeNameMatch.put(departement, n);
         break;
    }
}
```

Followed by the following every time an agent needs to find its arrival node :

```
v_arrivalNode = col_nodeNameMatch.get(departement);
```

Thank you Stuart for the much more efficient suggestion of using a Map.

Comment: You'd setup a *map* from node name to the actual node instead of a list like this (which means looping through the whole list each time to find the entry you want). Also, `getName` is very expensive computationally so much better to setup a map once from name to the actual node objects, and then use that to get nodes for names. (Here you are calling `getName` many times unnecessarily.)